# If $S\subseteq \{1,2,...,15\}$ has more than $5$ elements, then there are two distinct subsets of $S$ with the same element sum.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, summation, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

> For any finite set $T$ of real numbers, $s(T)$ is the sum of its elements. Let $S\subseteq \{1,2,...,15\}$.  If $s(B)\ne s(C)$ for any disjoint subsets $B,C$ of $S$, then show that $|S|\le 5$.

Source : Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics

I know that $|S|\le 6$.  Because for any $X\subseteq S$, $0\le s(X) \le 1+2+...+15=120$.  If $|S|\ge 7$, then $S$ has $2^7>121$ subsets, so there are two subsets $B,C$ of $S$ with equal element sum.  We can assume that $B$ and $C$ are disjoint (otherwise, remove the intersection from $B,C$).

I also know that there is an example with $|S|=5$.  My example is $\{8,11,13,14,15\}$.  But how to exclude the case $|S|=6$?

Oh, if you know which contest this problem came from, that'd be great.  Apparently, the book cited a wrong competition because it says USAMO 1986, but this problem is not in USAMO 1986.  Thank you very much.

BTW here is what I know about the case $|S|=6$.  Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_6\}$ where $x_1<x_2<...<x_6$.  If $x_6<14$, then $s(S)\le 13+12+...+8=63$.  Since $S=\{8,9,...,12,13\}$ doesn't work we must have $s(S)<63$.  So $s(X)$ for $X\subseteq S$ can have at most $63$ possible values but $63<2^6$, so this is a contradiction.  Therefore, $x_6\ge 14$.  Then there are too many cases to consider for $x_5$.

Comment: This looks similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709271/42969

Comment: @MartinR I used the same argument as in the link you gave to show that $|S|\le 6$.  But the same idea doesn't work to get $|S|\le 5$ because $2^6=64$ is not more than the sum of $15,14,13,12,11,10$ (which is 75) unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|S|=6$. Note that the maximum sum of any $4$-element (or smaller) subset is $12+13+14+15=54$, so at most $55$ different sum values are taken by subsets of $S$ of size at most $4$. But at most $7$ different values are taken by subsets of $S$ of size $5$ or $6$ (since it only has this many subsets of size $5$ or $6$). So in total the number of sum values for subsets of $S$ is at most $62<2^6$.

Comment: +1. Another way to put it is that there are $1+6+15+20+15=57$ different subsets of size $\le 4$, and (as you say) only $55$ possible sums.